# Patching a simple c program with IDA PRO get segmentation fault

Tags: patch, ida

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int var=5;
  if(var==5) printf("Accesso effettuato!");
  else printf("Access denied");

}
```

I change the op code... in the hex edit like in this image but when I run my program I get a segmentation fault.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You get a segmentation fault because the opcode `83 05` means the instruction `ADD DWORD PTR [address],constant` where the `address` and `constant` are determined by the next five bytes `05 89 45 F4 75`. So in this case, the instruction is `ADD DWORD PTR [F4458905],75`. So you are referencing an invalid memory address.

Answer (score 1):

The original instruction is:

```
83 F9 05  cmp ecx, 5
```

It looks like you're trying to change that into a constant comaparison, something like:

```
83 05 05  cmp 5, 5     ; not what you think it is!
```

I doubt that such a beast even exists, since its usefulness would be questionable at best. Comparing two constants would seem to be a waste of silicon.

What you're *actually* changing it to is an instruction that almost certainly dereferences an invalid address).

As option one, you can replace that three byte sequence with one that sets the zero bit (since the check a few instructions down is a `jnz` instruction), and pad it out with enough `nop` operations to make it the same size.

Alternatively, look for a `cmp ecx, ecx` statement (again with appropriate `nop` padding) so that you can be certain *all* flags are set correctly. This is, according to the GNU assembler `as`:

```
39 c9      cmp  %ecx, %ecx
90         nop
```

Comment: Cmp ecx,ecx is 83 F9 F9? Anyway thanks for you answer, I understand My error

Comment: @Usi, the opcodes aren't that simple, you need to get an assembler, or IDA Pro should be able to do that for you.